# plotting the latent space of a GAN

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, gan

I am working on gans and wanted to know how I can plot the latent space of gan. Like I have a latent space of shape (50,250). So it is an n-d array of length 50 and 250 points representing each one of them. I wanted to know a good way to plot them and also a way to make it an interactive graph of points where I can hover my mouse to see the transition from one latent point to another. I checked online but I can't find anything which can act as a reference. I was hoping someone could guide me on how to achieve this task. I tried plotting the latent dimensions by using plotly express, but that's all I can do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a trained GAN that already generates images in the target domain.
The videos you see of latent space walks where the image is morphing are done by picking a starting point in the space (a 250 dimensional space in your case) and picking a vector for the direction to move in (also 250 dimensional). The first dimension (50) in your example is really just arbitrary.

You can't really visualize the actual space itself because it has 250 dimensions and anything past 3 becomes pretty much nonsense. You can visualize the image created by the generator at a given point as it moves through the space though.

A simple pseudocode would be something like this -

Pick random point in latent space called "a"
Pick another random point in latent space called "b"
Pick a number of steps to take called "s" (this determines how fast the morphing happens, 10 for example)
v = (b - a) / s (this gives the vector pointing from a to b)
for s number of steps do:
generate image at point a
a += v

then pick a new point b to move towards and calculate v again, and repeat